# Nginx: 403 Forbidden on some files extensions

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2

Hello I am using Amazon Ec2 with Nginx.
I recently setup nginx and when I for example access blog.com/index.php it shows up in the browser correctly but when I access other file extension like JPEG, PNG, JS etc the file becomes 403.

Here is the error log.

```
[error] 5637#0: *132 open() "/var/www/html/js/jquery.js" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 10.000.00.00, server: blog.com, request: "GET /js/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1", host: "blog.com"
```

The permission stats on the js file (403 Forbiddon)

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user 93636 /var/www/html/js/jquery.js
```

The permission stats on the index.php file

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user 1281  /var/www/html/index.php
```

My Nginx conf file:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  4;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  8096;
    multi_accept on;
    use epoll;
}


http {
    charset UTF-8;
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  off;

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush     on;
    tcp_nodelay        on;
    server_tokens     off;

    keepalive_timeout  10;
    client_header_timeout 10;
    client_body_timeout 10;
    reset_timedout_connection on;
    send_timeout 10;
    limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=addr:5m;
    limit_conn addr 100;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_static on;
    gzip_http_version 1.0;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_min_length 1024;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    index   index.html index.htm index.php;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        root         /var/www/html;
        location / {
        }
        error_page  404              /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
        }
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }
        location ~* \.php$ {
        location ~* \.php$ {
          fastcgi_index   index.php;
          fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
          include         fastcgi_params;
          fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
          fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
        }

    }


    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name blog.com;

      location / {
          root    /var/www/html;
          index   index.html index.htm index.php;
      }

      location ~* \.php$ {
      ssi on;
      root /var/www/html;
      fastcgi_param HTTP_USER_AGENT  $http_user_agent;
      fastcgi_index   index.php;
      fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
      include         fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    /var/www/html$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;

      }

    }

}
```

Comment: You need to check the permissions of _all_ the containing directories.

Comment: yep that was it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the file/directory permissions with `ls -alh` or `stat` command. Seems might be a permission/ownership issue.

Answer (score 0):

In order for a file to be readable, not only the file needs read permissions, but also *all the parent directories* need read permissions. My guess is while the file jquery.js has the right permissions:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user 93636 /var/www/html/js/jquery.js
```

, the directory js hasn't:

```
-rwxr-x--- 1 ec2-user ec2-user 93636 /var/www/html/js
```

In this case nginx, which run under another user (for instance `www-data` or `nginx`) has no read permission on the containing directory, and hence cannot access the file jquery.js. The solution is to either change the permission of the "js" directory, or change ownership to the nginx user.

Comment: Actually nginx doesn't need `r` permission for directory. It needs `x` permission, to get inside the directory. `r` is used to get list of files in directory. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Permissions